# What is the View that is the argument in an onClick?

Tags: android, button, view, onclick

I have created a custom class `CustomButton` in which I have extended the `Button` class and added some extra `private` properties along with some setters and getters. In a separate activity, I wanted to invoke an `onClickListener()` with an `onClick` method within that would allow me to access these methods e.g.

```
onClick(View v) {
v.getPropertyICreated();
//Then do something with that property
}
```

However, it seems in Eclipse that I cannot call getProperty() on my view. I had assumed the View that is the argument is in this case the button.

1) What is the view that is the argument of the onClick?

2) And how would I be able to debug in the future to see what the view is exactly? (i.e. what method could I call on a view within Log.d(String arg, String arg) so that I could see what type of View it is)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view v is indeed the view on which you set the onclicklistener. I don't know the method getProperty(). You can test this if you cast the View to the right type (CustomButton or Button) and log e.g Button.getText().

Comment: Sorry, I just kind of made everything generic, created a method called `getProperty` though I probably should have named it `getCustomProperty`. However, as to your answer to my second question, why would I
a) have to cast the View? Isn't that an unchecked cast? and
b) what happens if my button does not have text in it?

Comment: You have to cast it, because the View v doesn't have your custom method and other methods like getText().
If your button doesn't have text, getText() will return an empty String ("")

Comment: Great, thanks! Accepted your answer as it is the only one which answers both of my questions :-)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to cast it to your own type first in order to access your methods, since your type is a subclass of `Button`, which is a subclass of `View`:

```
onClick(View v) {
CustomButton myButton = (CustomButton) v;
myButton.getProperty();
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to cast the View to your custom view, for example:

```
onClick(View v) {
CustomButton customButton = (CustomButton) v;

customButton.getProperty();
}
```